# Отображение товаров на главной WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите как сделать чтобы на главной странице магазина отображение товаров было рандом? Где в коде найти эти функции?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто изменить глобальный цикл. Случайную сортировку можно изменить через с помощью orderby -> rand. Укажите правильное условие. Например для главной страницы магазина:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );
function my_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
    if( $wp_query->main_query() && $wp_query->is_shop() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Где мне вставить этот код?

Comment: в functions.php